# echo stmt to be executed

Tags: php, ubuntu, background

```
<?php
while(true)
    {
    set_time_limit(2);
    $reas ="wake up from sleep!!!!!!!!!! \n ";
    echo $reas;
    sleep(5);
   // $readlen = 0;
    }
?>
```

i have this code. when i give

```
sudo php p1.php &
```

it only displays the process id.

i work in ubuntu

please help me

i want the echo statement in my code to be executed when i give   sudo php p1.php &

what i want is ,the echo statement(i e) the output of this code "wake up" to be printed when i give   php p1.php&.

the code works fine when i don't give "&" (i e) php p1.php alone

but,i want the exact thing which is running in foreground should run in background

how can i achieve this?

are there any alternative codes for this?

thanks in advance

Comment: I can't see stmt anywhere in your code....

Comment: see i have an echo stmt.echo reas

Comment: @user2427170 I suggest to you paste your code as you are trying to eant to run, cause if I try to run this snipped, it works!

Comment: @user2427170: there is only `echo $reas;`. I agree with @Carlos. paste you code in [codepad.org](http://codepad.org)

Comment: this is my code. it works when i gine php p1.php  but not php p1.php&. this & is to check how the code runs in background.if i give php p1.php& it gives me only the process id not the output.i want output(ie) wake up stmt to be printed

Comment: @user2427170 you are right, if you run $ php php1.php& you won see anything, cause the job will be run on background indefinitely, and you could continue working on the console

Comment: ayo this is my full code.i just want to run this echo stmt in background. i am a beginner to php.

Comment: @user2427170 in order to help you I am give you one point for no having minus, I will answer after edir your post

Comment: pls believe me.this is my full code and i have edited it too .now read and see

Comment: @user2427170, as the past comments, there is not a stm code, just is simple plain echo script, I though I have understood you, please check the edition, I will give you an answer and check if that runs for you

Comment: i want that echo stmt only to be printed in background

Comment: @jansrkl that is ok, but remember, in background means that the code will be running on a hide way, it means, any pinting will be seen

Comment: @jansrkl try to be carefull with your post, always there are stupid people that dont respect or encorauge new coders, and any new one just give -1 points, they dont take care of newbies.. are just stupids

Answer (score 1):

The `&` character at the end of the command simply makes the process to run in the background.

Use `nohup` command to echo the output to a file.

In your case it will be :

```
nohup php p1.php>/path/to/output_file &
```

Answer (score 0):

As I have understood you, whe you use the "&" operator at the last character on an order, you wull have your order running on background, no messages will be displayed, and if you have any print, whell It will be lost. Is a good using some thing like

```
$ php script.php > /dev/null &
```

On this way you will sending your print to null, but if you need the log of then, your could use something like

```
$ php script.php > script.log &
```

and you check the print when you need with:

```
$ tail -f script.log
```

on any of 1 on 3 orders, your will have your console showing the messages, the difference is that you could have your code running and you could hice message on any way without lost them

I hope it could help you on what you need

Comment: when i give the above comments it says file cannot open input file p2.php

Comment: thanks u thought u should help me. i think u dint understand me. i created a file p2.php.then i typed my code above. pls that is my full code. as iam a beginer iam just trying with a small code.when i execute the code, the correct output is displayed.but,when i add "&", i am just getting the process id and with your suggestion, i am getting process id along with the warning "could not open p2.php".i want the output of the code to be displayed when i add &     hope u understood now

Comment: As expplain you before, there is no a way to get the any echo when you use the & operator, cause any message will be sent to no place

Comment: Probably you could use an extra log file for been displayed using tail when you need, but there is not other way, remember "running on background" is "run without you notice is running", then no print, not  messages, none

Comment: Chec the answer that I giving you, I ma usig a log file that you could access on any time that you need and close when you didnt need, but your script continue running and, messages continue  benn sening to a log file

Comment: how to create a log file.are there any websites to teach this

Comment: check the asnwer man! I am giving that answer to you "$ php script.php > script.log &" just set the output to a file, just that, is the simplest way

Comment: $ php yourphpscript.php > afileto.log &

Comment: if i have understood correctly i have to create a log file named script.log in the same directory and then use the above code

Comment: No, that is part of you *nix systems as your ubuntu, your shell will give your php file that send your script output to other place, if it doesnt exists, it will be created, ">" will create a new one file each time that you runs your code. ">>" just will use the old one log ( if exists ) and append messages at the bottom file

Comment: when i give php p2.php > file.log & , it gives a process id and says could not open the input file p2.php

Comment: is a p2.php file? that message is saying you that p2.php file doesnt exists

Comment: no the file exits. i checked the www directory and also opened that file in ubuntu terminal

Comment: Are running on terminal or web? both are diferent on execution

Comment: i m running a terminal

Comment: well , then make a "ls -l", if you seen your file there, then you could use it, also you net to be sure the name is ok, also, you need permissoin, are you using an own directory?